# Toggle class on Multiple Elements with UI Feedback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, toggleclass

I have a list (spaces just for visual clarity):

```
<li class="a">      A     </li>
<li class="b">      B     </li>
<li class="c">      C     </li>
<li class="a b">    A B   </li>
<li class="a c">    A C   </li>
<li class="b c">    B C   </li>
<li class="a b c">  A B C </li>
```

I have a series of 'controls':

```
<a class="show-a" href="#">A</a>
<a class="show-b" href="#">B</a>
<a class="show-c" href="#">C</a>
<a class="show-all active" href="#">ALL</a>
```

I have some CSS:

```
li           {color: red; }
 .deactivate {color: #ddd; }
a            {color: #ddd; }
 .active     {color: blue; }
```

**I want to do two things:**

1. When the corresponding `<a>` control is clicked, add/remove the `.deactivate` class to the respective `<li>`s. e.g. if `.show-a` is clicked, apply `.deactivate` to all the elements without an `.a` class. And, thus, remove the `.deactivate` class from any `<li>`s that no longer require it.
2. Reflect the current selection in the controls. i.e. add/remove the `.active` class to the respective anchor links. (this is the part I can never find an answer for).

**NOTE:**

- Only one control can be `.active` at any given time. Like radio buttons, but more style-able via CSS.
- It seems like the better solutions out there use jQuery and toggleClass.

**RE Other Answers:** there are many (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4uK/2/) but

- none that address #2
- most show/hide rather than toggle a class
- very few are explained, and so it's hard to iterate on the answers and understand how they work (which is my ultimate goal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the `data-selector` attribute to hold the selectors for what items related to a particular link. It helps makes the JS really clean.

As for the active link, we simply remove `.active` from all links and add it to the one that was just clicked.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCcZZ/1/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.links a').click(function () {

        // Remove .active from all links then add to the clicked one
        $('.links a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Remove .active from all lis then use the attribute data-selector to set
        // the relevant items
        $('.letters li').removeClass('active');
        $(this.getAttribute('data-selector')).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="links">
    <a class="show-a" href="#" data-selector=".a">A</a>
    <a class="show-b" href="#" data-selector=".b">B</a>
    <a class="show-c" href="#" data-selector=".c">C</a>
    <a class="show-all active" href="#" data-selector=".a,.b,.c">ALL</a>
</div>

<ul class="letters">
    <li class="a">      A     </li>
    <li class="b">      B     </li>
    <li class="c">      C     </li>
    <li class="a b">    A B   </li>
    <li class="a c">    A C   </li>
    <li class="b c">    B C   </li>
    <li class="a b c">  A B C </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    background-color:#AAA;
}
```

Comment: close but i don't want to show/hide elements. i want to apply a specific css class (rather than hiding). (thanks!)

Comment: can you update the comments in the JS to reflect that change please? just for future generations and all. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#user-controls div").first().addClass('active'); // <---add this line
    $("#user-controls").on('click', 'div', function () {
       $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); //<--and this
       var classToShow = this.id.split('-')[1],
        filter = classToShow === "all" ? 'div' : '.' + classToShow;
        $("#devices").children().show().not(filter).hide();
    });
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4uK/4/)

here i made a css class `.active{}`:

```
.active {
  background:red !important;
  color:yellow;
}
```

and just after the page load first of the divs in the `#user-controls` which is `all` should be applied `.active` css class.

with this one:

```
$("#user-controls div").first().addClass('active');
```

then if click happens on other links then here in this case `.siblings()` is the useful function.

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

lets break it up:

```
$(this).addClass('active')
```

This line adds the class `.active` to the clicked link and

```
.siblings().removeClass('active');
```

This one removes the other link classes applied on other links at same level.